# Multiple definition in non-existent directory

Tags: c, directory, header-files, multiple-definition-error

I'm trying to compile a source file and I'm running into the multiple definition error in a directory that does not exist.

Here's the situation:

1. I'm compiling a program, let's call it prog1.c. This program compiles fine
2. I can link other programs (prog2.c, prog3.c) to this library without issue
3. When I try linking a static library to prog1.c, I get a multiple definition error, where the first definition of the conflicting function comes from a non-existent directory

Here's what's weird:

1. The directory .../lab5/util/list.c does not exist! (See error code below)
2. Only a subset of my functions from my list.c are defined more than once. Not all functions in list.o have this issue

ERROR:

```
../util/libname.a(prog.o): In function 'function1':
.../dir_ok/util/prog.c:42: multiple definition of 'function1'   // dir_ok exists
../util/libname.a(prog.o): .../dir_foo/util/prog.c:41: first defined here  // dir_foo exists, but there is no dir_foo/util.
```

Makefile:

```
# Makefile
# Flags
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -pedantic -std=c11
CLEANLOC=src

#directory names
VPATH = ./:./src/:../util/

UTILDIR = ../util/
UTILFLAG = -llibnameutil
UTILLIB = $(UTILDIR)liblibnameutil.a
UTILC = list of .c, including prog.c that gives the error
UTILH = list of .h, including prog.h that gives the error

EXEC = foo
OBJS = foo.o
SRCS = foo.c, foo.h

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS) $(UTILLIB)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -L$(UTILDIR) $(UTILFLAG)

$(UTILLIB): $(UTILC) $(UTILH)  
    cd $(UTILDIR); make;

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^
```

Conceptually, what could be the issue here? I am willing to post more code if needed. I think the issue is in my prog1.c because prog2.c and prog3.c all work fine with the static library and prog.o.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I can't believe I made such a trivial mistake. The library was not being removed by my Make: clean command and it was just an old library being used